# Wordhunt program in java

Tags: java

This is what it do ... 
I have a .txt file that i have stored in a 2d Array and it works ...
heres the problem im supposed to search for a word in the table and i can't figure out a way for me to compare the letters in the arrays and return it's index.... (so basically i want to find a letter in the 2d array and i want it to return it's index int c[][])
the real assignment was like a wordhunt puzzle ( where it can find it horizontal vertical diagonal (left and right) aswell as backwards ( in the said directions) but i'm pretty sure i can get around it once i know how i can get the indexes of the 2st letter of the word i search for

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Mp6 {


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    FileReader a = new FileReader("data/Data.txt");
    BufferedReader ss = new BufferedReader(a);
    char wla[][];
     int x = 80;
     int y = 80;
    wla = new char [x][y];
    String d;
    Scanner p = new Scanner(System.in);
    int c = 0;
    int n = 0 ; 


    try {
        for( c = 0; c < x; c++){ 
                d = ss.readLine(); 
        for ( n = 0; n<y;n++){
                wla[c][n]=d.charAt(n);
                System.out.print(wla[c][n]); 
                }
                 System.out.println("");
            }

        System.out.println("Search for:");
         String h = p.nextLine();
         h=h.toUpperCase();
         char [] ph = new char[h.length()];
         int counter = 0;
         for(counter = 0 ; counter < h.length();counter++){
             ph[counter]=h.charAt(counter);
             System.out.print(ph[counter]);
         }
         //horizontal


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

}

http://www.mediafire.com/file/6ti20007cvyi4y7/DATA.txt

Comment: Whats this got to do with javascript?

Comment: How is this related to JavaScript? If not related please edit and remove the tag, it's confusing..

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you right, you want to search for the word in 2d array in all directions. In that case the best algorithm should sound like this:

1. Loop through the array finding
   the first letter of the word.
2. After finding one - search in all
   directions for remaining letters.

This is a sample of how it can be done:

```
char[] word = getWordToFind();
char[][] array = getArrayWhereToSearch();

//Search for first letter of the word
for (int x = 0; x<array.length;x++) {
    for (int y=0; y<array[x].length;y++) {
        //If the first letter is found
        if (array[x][y] == word[0]) {
            //Search in all directions
            if (searchEast(array, word, x, y)) {
                println(String.format("Word match found! X: %d, Y: %d, direction: '%s'", x, y, "east"));
            }
            if (searchSouth(array, word, x, y)) {
                println(String.format("Word match found! X: %d, Y: %d, direction: '%s'", x, y, "south"));
            }
            //More directions if needed
            ...
        }
    }
}

public boolean searchEast(char[][] array, char[] word, int startX, int startY) {
    //If the word can't fit to the right
    if (x >= array.length-word.length) {
        return false;
    }

    //Search the remaining letters to the right starting from startX+1
    for (int dx = 1; dx<word.length;dx++) {
        if (array[startX+dx] != word[dx]) { //If the letter mismatches
            return false;
        }
    }

    //All letters matched
    return true;
}

public boolean searchSouth(char[][] array, char[] word, int startX, int startY) {
    //If the word can't fit to the bottom
    if (y >= array[startX].length-word.length) {
        return false;
    }

    //Search the remaining letters to the bottom starting from startY+1
    for (int dy = 1; dy<word.length;dy++) {
        if (array[startX][startY+dy] != word[dy]) { //If the letter mismatches
            return false;
        }
    }

    //All letters matched
    return true;
}
```

Comment: thx i got my indexes,, anyway did you just code this your self or is there original link and if there is original link can i have?